# How to stop event bubbling on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, events

I have a checkbox that I want to perform some Ajax action on the click event, however the checkbox is also inside a container with its own click behaviour that I don't want to run when the checkbox is clicked. This sample illustrates what I want to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container').addClass('hidden');
  $('#header').click(function() {
    if ($('#container').hasClass('hidden')) {
      $('#container').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('#container').addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
  $('#header input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event) {
    // Do something
  });
});
```

```css
#container.hidden #body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I can't figure out how to stop the event bubbling without causing the default click behaviour (checkbox becoming checked/unchecked) to not run.

Both of the following stop the event bubbling but also don't change the checkbox state:

```
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

Comment: I found an article on this matter that might be helpful to other Stack Overflowers. [Quick Tip: Click Table Row to Trigger a Checkbox Click](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/12/quick-tip-click-table-row-to-trigger-a-checkbox-click)

Answer (score 382, accepted):

replace

```
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

with

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

***event.stopPropagation()***

> Stops the bubbling of an event to
>   parent elements, preventing any parent
>   handlers from being notified of the
>   event.

***event.preventDefault()***

> Prevents the browser from executing
>   the default action. Use the method
>   isDefaultPrevented to know whether
>   this method was ever called (on that
>   event object).

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work for me, but return false did.

Comment: If you are binding the event using `.live()` method then this will not work. You will have to use `return false;` itself.

Comment: This works using jQuery's `.on()` method (live is now deprecated). I could not figure out why return false wasn't working.

Comment: i spent quite a while to figure out that event.preventDefault() was not showing the check mark in IE8, but worked well in other browsers. I found this answer after I fixed and then googling with preventDefault,IE8, checkbox as keyword, brought me here.

Comment: did'nt work for.. but this two line did(without return false) --> event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();

Comment: keeping event.preventDefault() along with event.stopPropagation() is what fixed it for me.  Otherwise I was getting two click events each time.  I'm using materializecss in Rails 5 which may be effecting things

Answer (score 34):

Use the stopPropagation method:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 30):

Don't forget IE:

```
if (event.stopPropagation) {    // standard
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {    // IE6-8
        event.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

Comment: This answer is from 2012. In 2015 please do forget IE.

Comment: This applies to IE9 as well. My IE9 test machine chokes on stopPropagation(), but likes cancelBubble(). And some people/orgs are still using IE9 in 2016, sadly. Those of us with corporate customers can't ignore that.

Comment: i love ie5 in 2019

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, try `stopPropagation()`.

And there is a second handler to try: `event.cancelBubble = true;` It's a IE specific handler, but it is supported in at least FF. Don't really know much about it, as I haven't used it myself, but it might be worth a shot, if all else fails.

Answer (score 6):

When using jQuery you do not need to call a stop function separate.

You can just return `false` in the event handler

This will stop the event and cancel bubbling..

Also see [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

From the jQuery docs:

> These handlers, therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by calling `event.stopPropagation()` or returning `false`.

Answer (score 5):

This is an excellent example for understanding event bubbling concept. Based on the above answers, the final code will look like as mentioned below. Where the user Clicks on checkbox the event propagation to its parent element 'header' will be stopped using `event.stopPropagation();`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#container').addClass('hidden');
            $('#header').click(function() {
                if($('#container').hasClass('hidden')) {
                    $('#container').removeClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $('#container').addClass('hidden');
                }
            });
          $('#header input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event) {
              if (event.stopPropagation) {    // standard
                   event.stopPropagation();
               } else {    // IE6-8
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
               }
          });     
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Credit to [@mehras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990426/mehras) for the code. I just created a snippet to demonstrate it because I thought that would be appreciated and I wanted an excuse to try that feature.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container').addClass('hidden');
  $('#header').click(function() {
    if ($('#container').hasClass('hidden')) {
      $('#container').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('#container').addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
  $('#header input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event) {
    if (event.stopPropagation) { // standard
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else { // IE6-8
      event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.2em
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"><input type="checkbox" />Checkbox won't bubble the event, but this text will.</div>
<div id="container">click() bubbled up!</div>
```

Comment: Code that actually shows how to use event variable, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a trick that worked for me:

```
handleClick = e => {
    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Explanation: I attached `handleClick` to a backdrop of a modal window, but it also fired on every click inside of a modal window (because it was IN the backdrop div). So I added the condition `(e.target === e.currentTarget)`, which is only fulfilled when a backdrop is clicked.

Comment: can you explain your answer as to how it is working, so that future readers get a clear picture.

Answer (score 1):

In angularjs this should works:

```
event.preventDefault(); 
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: This is not AngularJS, it is vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert it into a div and add it an event listener e.stopPropagation(), as follows:

**HTML**

```
        <div class="parent">
  
<div class="checkboxdiv">

  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Check" class="checkbox">

</div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    document.querySelector('div.checkboxdiv').addEventListener('click',function(e){

  e.stopPropagation()


})
```