# Javascript error1

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript for required field validation,i have used alert box,after clicking ok in alert box then also controls goes to server side code for save click

```
function IsFieldEmpty() {
    var txtAgent_Name = document.getElementById("<%=txtAgent_Name.ClientID %>");

    if (txtAgent_Name.value == "") {
        alert('Please Enter Agent Name');
        txtAgent_Name.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is incredibly hard to understand, what are you asking for? What have you tried already?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you show us how `isFieldEmpty` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that some event handler is still submitting data after showing an `alert` informing of a validation error, you'll probably need to make the event handler function return `false` after showing the `alert` , in order to prevent further processing of the event.

As pointed out by @Bergi in his comment, and if you're using JQuery or another framework, you might need to use `stopPropagation()` or equivalent. See

- [How to stop event bubbling on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1164213/851811)
- [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1357118/851811).

**UPDATE**

Seeing the code posted, it might be important to remark that the `return false` is being done inside the `IsFieldEmpty` function. That means that `false` is the return value for `IsFieldEmpty`. Take into account that if you're submitting data in a similar way to this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="IsFieldEmpty()">
```

`IsFieldEmpty` will return false but the event handler won't. If it's the case, you should change it to:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return IsFieldEmpty()">
```

and make `IsFieldEmpty` return `true` when validations are passed.

```
function IsFieldEmpty() {
    var txtAgent_Name = document.getElementById("<%=txtAgent_Name.ClientID %>");

    if (txtAgent_Name.value == "") {
        alert('Please Enter Agent Name');
        txtAgent_Name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i have returned false then also control is going to Save click

Comment: `return false` does stop propagation, but does not prevent the default event. @Becks: show us your code, especially how you attach the listener.

Comment: where should i define PreventDefault()??

Comment: @Becks I've updated the answer. Make sure the _event handler_ returns `false`, not just the function it calls.

Comment: Thanks Xavi i got it,i forgot to write return before calling Function on OnclientClick