# How to make a JavaScript class toggle persistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/brunorl/kL70z8ky/3/)

```
    var main = function() {
    $('.article').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('current')) {
                $(this).children('.description').toggle("slow");
        }
        else {
                $('.article').removeClass('current');
                $('.description').hide();
                $(this).addClass('current');
                $(this).children('.description').toggle("slow");
        };
 });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Hello, I would like to know how to learn how to do a few things with my little on-click toggle list:

Im having a hard time on how to make this toggle list to remain persistent after a user clicks on an already opened article. Right now the way I have it setup the current article will toggle whenever clicked on, I would like it to remain open and to only close when clicked on the heading itself (opposed to anywhere in the item).

Also 
+ How to create an open/close all toggle link 
+ continuity visual cues that shows list is expandable and if it is either open or closed that will fit this style

Comment: A toggle toggles - that's what it is for. For persistence, you want addClass/removeClass, not toggle.

Comment: Then attaching the toggle handler to the `.article` class probably isn't what you want, if you want close-toggling to be handled differently.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Im still not sure why I got negative points for asking a legit question tho..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the `.article .item` and not the `.article`

```
var main = function() {
    $('.article .item').click(function() {
        var article = $(this).closest('.article');
        if(article.hasClass('current')) {
                article.children('.description').toggle("slow");
        }
        else {
                $('.article').removeClass('current');
                $('.description').hide();
                article.addClass('current');
                article.children('.description').toggle("slow");
        };
   });
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/kL70z8ky/5/

Comment: Thank you! Great simple solution, now I understand my mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want a click on a child item to cause closure of your main heading, you need to stop the event propagation.

Please check for full syntax/usage: [How to stop event bubbling on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click)

Usage:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a nother aproach:

```
$('.article').click(function () {
    $(".article").not($(this).addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
    $('.description').not($('.description',this).slideDown()).slideUp();
});
```