# Why does listener activate twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I have the following html:

```
<ul id="all-terminals">

        <li data-terminal-id="101" class="">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="terminal" class="all" data-terminal-id="101">
                <a ...></a>

               ...
            </label>
        </li>

        <li data-terminal-id="100" class="active">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="terminal" class="all" data-terminal-id="100">
                <a ..></a>

               ...
            </label>
        </li>

        <li data-terminal-id="102" class="">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="terminal" class="all" data-terminal-id="102">
                <a...></a>

              ...
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I wrote the following listener:

```
$(document).on('click', '#all-terminals li label', function(){alert(123)});
```

when I click on label, I see that alert executes twise.

Why?

Comment: I can't reproduce. http://jsfiddle.net/52vLfcn8/

Comment: Can not be reproduced -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lceu6ac1/**

Comment: Not happening in Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/Lfq9dkgt/

Comment: I'm running all of your jsfiddles and I'm getting the alert twice...?

Comment: Try preventing event bubbling by adding this after the alert: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13900163/1913729

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc click to the 3 dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure why, but `mouseup` works.

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '#all-terminals li label', function(){alert(123)});
```

Answer (score 3):

Clicking a `label` automatically creates a click event on an `input` within it.

Assuming all your labels have inputs, you can simply change to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#all-terminals li input', function(event) {
  alert(123);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0st5u6us/)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The currently marked answer is a work around.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc please explain why this workaround works ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow The answer (by CrazyPaste) is changing the event type from `click` to `mouseup`. That's a work around. Rick Hitchcock is fixing the `click` event and also explaining why this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think bubbling is occurring in your case .
Read about on [Bubbling and Capturing](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiyltPFvpLGAhULULwKHUn8AJo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjavascript.info%2Ftutorial%2Fbubbling-and-capturing&ei=2i5_VbLBO4ug8QXJ-IPQCQ&usg=AFQjCNEkBCjcQ__JRdUiNHJxzksZF7prSw&sig2=Jc3lpVG9GR2xq_T4bS4Rbg)

Comment: Is it normal or I should avoid twise fires?

Comment: Avoiding it will be better 
Use instead `$('#all-terminals li label')` it will work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I think that when you click on the label, you hit 2 of its child overlapping elements. Because they are part of the label but still separate elements, it fires two click events on label.

On the fiddle, it appears the it's the [a] element overlapping the ...

Comment: Should I avoid this behaviour ?

Comment: That's what is causing the problem. Usually it's okay, but it can cause problems in cases like click detection or hovering