# Clicking a button added by JavaScript clicks through it as well

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I'm working on a script that adds a button that floats on top of a Facebook user's profile photo thumbnail.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Facebook thumbail button]

This button, when clicked, returns the Facebook ID of the profile that is being viewed in a prompt. That part works fine (but you'd need to be logged in and looking at a profile besides yours, otherwise there'd be a missing element).

Screenshot:

[image: prompt screenshot]

What's bothering me though, is after clicking the button, and pressing Cancel or Okay in the prompt, the click actually goes through the button and clicks the profile picture thumbnail itself. A single click is clicking both items!

**Is there any way we can make it so that the area below the button itself is not clickable? But the rest of the profile picture is?**

I've tried searching on this topic but couldn't find much results. Even if I try to search for something like "Add padding below/under button JavaScript", I'm getting padding around the button, and not directly below it
in a z-axis point of view.

Here's the script code, you can copy paste it in the console directly. That is, if you have a Facebook account and are logged in. Also this only works on profiles besides yours (otherwise `data-profileid` would be missing).

```
// Create the button
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("FBID");    // To replace with icon
btn.appendChild(t);

// Add a listener
btn.addEventListener("click", getFBID);

// Styling (positioning)
btn.style.display="block";
btn.style.position="absolute";
btn.style.top="4px";
btn.style.right="4px";

// Function to get Facebook ID
function getFBID() {
    prompt("Copy it:", document.querySelectorAll("[data-profileid]")[0].getAttribute("data-profileid"));
}

// Append button to profile picture
document.getElementsByClassName("profilePicThumb")[0].appendChild(btn);
```

Oh yeah, I feel the reason why this is happening is because I am appending to an anchor link. Just in case this info would be useful.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: put a z-index on the button, which is higher than the profile pic

Comment: have had a look at `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` methods of javascript event handlers?

Comment: @JordanHendrix, tried that earlier even though I feel that's more for positioning, didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal, tried prevenDefault, but haven't tried stopPropagation, will try that now, thanks!

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal, stopPropagation made it worse haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prevent the default actions for the click like this:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  getFBID();
  return false;
});
```

**EDIT**: use event.stopPropagation();

(compare to this thread [How to stop event bubbling on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click))

Comment: That worked! I've tried both preventDefault and stopPropagation, but never tried them both together and that did it! Thanks :)

Comment: @user3637541: Well according to the standards, **returning false will eventually stop propagation and prevent default** I guess so **what's the point** of writing it again? (although not sure if all the browsers follow those standards)

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/3882583) the `return false` stops bubbling when it's within a jQuery event handler. Guess it's different with me since I'm just using plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Create the button
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("FBID");    // To replace with icon
btn.appendChild(t);

// Add a listener
btn.addEventListener("click", getFBID);

// Styling (positioning)
btn.style.display="block";
btn.style.position="absolute";
btn.style.top="4px";
btn.style.right="4px";

// Function to get Facebook ID
function getFBID() {
    prompt("Copy it:", document.querySelectorAll("[data-profileid]")[0].getAttribute("data-profileid"));
    return false;                   // Try returning false here..
}

// Append button to profile picture
document.getElementsByClassName("profilePicThumb")[0].appendChild(btn);
```

`getFBID` in this case is a callback for the event that is raised on the click of the button. returning `false` will make sure that the event is not propagated to its parent and hence will not raise the parent's event or call the eventhandler.

Comment: Correct (so up-voted), but an explanation would be nice too :)

Comment: @Archer, unfortunately, it hasn't fixed it for me.

Comment: In order to further help, I'd need to see the HTML as well. Always remember that HTML and Javascript always go hand in hand so never post Javascript alone and expect a working solution