# stop the mouse down event of body on SVG mouse down

Tags: javascript, svg, onmousedown

Here, i am trying to stop the mouse down event of body when mouse down of SVG if fired. I also tried the `event.stopPropagation` but here it is not working.
Here is my code.

```
var svgElem=document.getElementById("mySVG");
svgElem.onmousedown=function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("svg down");
    }
document.body.onmousedown=function(){
        console.log("body down");
}
```

body mouse down is fired after SVG mouse down.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/27rstd0p/)

Comment: That fiddle works in chrome and doesn't in firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop event bubbling on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you were pretty close. The following sample does what I think you want.

```js
function redClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('red clicked');
}
function bodyClick(e) {
  console.log('body clicked');
}
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById('noclick').addEventListener('mousedown',redClick,false);
 document.body.addEventListener('mousedown',bodyClick,false);
}
```

```html
<div style="background:grey;width:100%;height:6em;">click me too.
<div id="noclick" style="color:white;width:50%;height:3em;background:red">click me :]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var svgElem=document.getElementById("mySVG");
svgElem.onmousedown=function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("svg down")
        console.log("svg down");
    }
document.body.onmousedown=function(){
        console.log("body down");
        alert("body down")
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mySVG">
    hey svg
  </div>
</body>
```

Above example works in chrome and doesn't in firefox.

Firefox is throwing error as it doesn't find `event` parameter in `svgElem.onmousedown`

change your code as below.

```
svgElem.onmousedown=function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("svg down");
    }
```