# onClick event of child component is not getting triggered for stacked parent and child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I have the following two components with thier respective `onClick()` handlers. Problem is `doSomethingElse` is never getting and directly `doSomething` is getting called.

```
<ParentComponent onClick={this.doSomething}>
   <ChildComponent onClick={this.doSomethingElse} />
</Parent>
```

`Child` is shown as like proover on `parent` using `z-index`.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  handleP = (e) => {
    alert("parent")
  };

  render() {
    return (

      <div onClick={this.handleP} style={{
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        zIndex: 100,
        position: 'absolute',
      }}>
      Parent Text
        <Child  />
      </div>          

    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  handleC = (e) => {
    alert("child")
  };

  render() {
    return (

      <div onClick={this.handleC} style={{
        left: 1,
        top: 1,
        zIndex: 1000,
        position: 'absolute',
      }}>
      Child Text  
      </div>          

    )
  }
}



React.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

[Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bopimupuho/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: can you create a working example and show the actual full code?

Comment: It would be useful if we know what Parent and Child Components are!

Comment: @MayankShukla added sample code please check edited question.
But in this example code is working but in my case its not working.

Comment: try to use the same structure as you are using in your actual code.

Comment: [It seems to be working fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/03xpqmkl2v).

Answer (score 0):

@SandipPingle the issue is because, by default a click event bubbles till window. So after the child handler is invoked the event bubbles to parent component. For that you need to stop the event propogation. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click) and this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5r472y3m0) for a sample fixed version based on this answer :)