# How to control multiple (click) events inside a table?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hello I hope the title is descriptive enough to understand my problem,

I have this HTML code. In `<td>` i have attached a `(click)` function. Inside this `<td>`, I have another `div` which also has a `(click)` function attached. When I click the button inside `<td>` both functions are triggered. 
But, I would like only the (click) in div to be triggered when I click it and not the `<td>` `(click)`. 
Is it possible to happen?

```
<td mat-cell align="center" *ngFor="let option of options; let opt_indx = index"
    (click)="optionsClicked(opt_indx, i);" id="defaultBadge-wrapper">

    <div *ngIf="!rowCommands[i].defaultSelected[opt_indx]" class="defaultBadge">
        <a class="badge badge-secondary" matTooltip="Click here to set this Option as Default"
            (click)="markDefault(i,option.id)">Default</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Typescript code

```
markDefault(index, option: string) {
    alert('this function triggered');
}

optionsClicked(option, rule) {
    alert('I dont want this function to be triggered when i click markDefault');
}
```

Comment: Can you post typescript code also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop event bubbling on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ts method pass the $event as param and include

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

or in the click event pass another function:

```
(click)="markDefault(i,option.id); event.stopPropagation();">Default</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `stoppropagation` to prevent the event from propagating

```
(click)="markDefault(i,option.id); event.stopPropagation();">Default</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `$event.stopPropagation()` to inner click.

```
<div *ngIf="!rowCommands[i].defaultSelected[opt_indx]" class="defaultBadge">
    <a class="badge badge-secondary" matTooltip="Click here to set this Option as Default"
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation();markDefault(i,option.id)">Default</a>
</div>
```